# How to create constructor with Null argumnet in Julia

Tags: julia

I want to create type Family with argument type Family but i want to create possibility with Null argument

```
type Family
    name:: AbstracDtring
    people:: Int
    dad:: Family
    mom:: Family

Family(name:: AbstractString, people::Int ) = new (name, people , NULL, NULL)


end
```

Can i do somthing with this i want create "object" with references to another object or without references

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Nullable` (http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/types/#nullable-types-representing-missing-values)

```
type Family
    name:: AbstractString
    people:: Int
    dad:: Nullable{Family}
    mom:: Nullable{Family}

Family(name:: AbstractString, people::Int ) = new(name, people, Nullable{Family}(), Nullable{Family}())

end
```

Answer (score 5):

You can call `new` with fewer arguments:

```
type Family
    name::AbstractString
    people::Int
    dad::Family
    mom::Family

    Family(name::AbstractString, people::Int) = new(name, people)
end
```

You can construct instances but until you've assigned the `.dad` and `.mom` fields, accessing them will cause an error:

```
julia> fam = Family("Jones", 3)
Family("Jones",3,#undef,#undef)

julia> fam.dad
ERROR: UndefRefError: access to undefined reference
 in eval(::Module, ::Any) at ./boot.jl:225
 in macro expansion at ./REPL.jl:92 [inlined]
 in (::Base.REPL.##1#2{Base.REPL.REPLBackend})() at ./event.jl:46

julia> fam.mom
ERROR: UndefRefError: access to undefined reference
 in eval(::Module, ::Any) at ./boot.jl:225
 in macro expansion at ./REPL.jl:92 [inlined]
 in (::Base.REPL.##1#2{Base.REPL.REPLBackend})() at ./event.jl:46

julia> fam.dad = fam
Family("Jones",3,Family(#= circular reference @-1 =#),#undef)

julia> fam.mom
ERROR: UndefRefError: access to undefined reference
 in eval(::Module, ::Any) at ./boot.jl:225
 in macro expansion at ./REPL.jl:92 [inlined]
 in (::Base.REPL.##1#2{Base.REPL.REPLBackend})() at ./event.jl:46
```

You can check if a field is defined or not using the `isdefined` function:

```
julia> isdefined(fam, :dad)
true

julia> isdefined(fam, :mom)
false
```

The `Nullable` approach works too but this is somewhat lighter weight.

Comment: I am surprised this works. Does it work for `immutable` as well?

Comment: It does but it's not terribly useful since you can't assign to the undefined fields after an instance is constructed.